# Existence of Euler product on critical line for $L(\chi,s) L(\overline{\chi},1-s)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, dirichlet-series, euler-product

Generally there is no Euler product for Dirichlet L-functions $L(\chi,s)$ in the critical strip.(cf [Is the Euler product formula always divergent for 0<Re(s)<1?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63714/is-the-euler-product-formula-always-divergent-for-0res1?s=7|1.6363))

But I would like to know if there is an Euler product for the following product (with $\chi$ a primitive characater):

$$L(\chi,s) L(\overline{\chi},1-s)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}    \chi(n)  \frac{1}{n^{1-s}}  \; \overline{ \chi(k)} \frac{1}{k^{s}}$$

in the specific case where $s=\frac{1}{2}+it$

as in this case (product is on prime numbers):

$$S_P(\chi)=\prod\limits_{p=1}^{P} (1-  \chi(p) p^{-s})^{-1}  (1- \overline{ \chi(p)} p^{s-1})^{-1}=  \prod\limits_{p=1}^{P} (1- ( \chi(p) p^{-\frac{1}{2}-it} +\overline{ \chi(p)} p^{-\frac{1}{2}+it})+ p^{-1})^{-1} $$

So the term $( \chi(p) p^{-\frac{1}{2}-it} +\overline{ \chi(p)} p^{-\frac{1}{2}+it})$ is real and if I take the log of the product it seems I have a sum with divergent terms going to $-\infty$ meaning the product converges.

$ln(S_P(\chi))= - \sum\limits_{p=1}^{P}- ( \chi(p) p^{-\frac{1}{2}-it} +\overline{ \chi(p)} p^{-\frac{1}{2}+it})- \sum\limits_{p=1}^{P}  p^{-1}+ ...$

So, is this correct and in this specific case an Euler product exits ?

Comment: It is sloppy to say "there is no Euler product" when you really mean to say "there is no *proof of convergence* of the Euler product." It'd be like saying the Riemann hypothesis is not true when you mean to say it is not proved yet to be true. For nontrivial $\chi$ it is plausible that the Euler product for $L(\chi,s)$ does converge when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$, but there is no proof of  that. On the critical line is a surprise: *if* $\prod_{p} 1/(1 - \chi(p)/\sqrt{p})$ converges to a nonzero value and $\chi$ is quadratic, that value must be not $L(\chi,1/2)$, but $\sqrt{2}L(\chi,1/2)$.

Comment: Dear Professor Conrad, Is there a reason why the factor $\sqrt{2}$ occurs? @KConrad

Comment: @DianbinBao, yes, see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/eulerprod.pdf. Computationally it is a "second moment" effect.

Comment: Dear Professor Conrad, you mean convergence of $\sum\limits_{p=1}^{P}- ( \chi(p) p^{-\frac{1}{2}-it} +\overline{ \chi(p)} p^{-\frac{1}{2}+it})$ is not proved and therefore proof that the proposed Euler product converges is pending also ? @KConrad

Comment: Certainly convergence is not yet proved, but more to the point I think it is completely unrealistic to expect convergence to be proved in our lifetime. Convergence of a partial Euler product for $L(\chi,s)$ at any point $s_0$ where $1/2 < {\rm Re}(s_0) < 1$ would imply $L(\chi,s)$ is nonvanishing for ${\rm Re}(s) > {\rm Re}(s_0)$, which goes beyond what anyone has ever shown (i.e., a vertical zero-free strip of positive width to the left of ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$).  That already looks very hard, so proving something similar at a point on the critical line seems even more remote. [Continued...]

Comment: Now in your case you are dealing with two products at once, so in your sum there is a certain amount of cancellation, but I don't see why that should make the task of proving convergence more feasible in any sense.